# How use hex::encode in Substrate offchain worker?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate

I'm calling `hex::encode` from offchain worker, but compilation fails with:

```
    state.serialize_field("account_id", &hex::encode( self.account_id.encode().as_slice() ) )?;
      |                                       ^^^^^^ not found in `hex`
```

My Cargo.toml contains:

```toml
[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    ...
    'hex/std'
]

[dependencies]
hex = { version='0.4.3', default-features=false }
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the "alloc" feature to Cargo.toml solved the problem:

```toml
hex = { version='0.4.3', default-features=false, features = ['alloc'] }
```